# Apache2 with PHP - Pages Not Loading Without Bypassing Cache

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have a weird issue where my PHP pages being served by Apache2 will not load on the page without having to bypass the browser cache (Ctrl+Shift+R).

If I got to mypage.com/test.php I get a browser erro page: The connection was reset (Firefox)
or Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data. (Chrome)

If I do a Ctrl+Shift+R on the page then the test.php which is just a call to phpinfo(), then the page loads normally and I see the PHP output.

I'm running on Ubuntu with a virtual host for the specific site using PHP 5.3.2. If I do a curl on the mypage.com/test.php on the server it loads the page fine. But not on PC browsers on or off the network.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to get Apache to serve the page without the CTRL+Shift+R?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_disk_cache.html#cacheexpirycheck

Comment: Tried enabling this mod along with the cache module as it says it's required. Didn't change anything.

Comment: @jonsinfinity    do you have a link to the problem page?

Comment: take a look at the apache logs to ensure it's not something silly going on in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try use something like https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ to get full text of requests and answers in browser.